# I need to calculate mean, median and std but asking the user numbers until user puts 0

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

count = 0
number = 1

while number != 0:
    number = int(input("Enter values"))
    print(np.mean(number))
    print(np.median(number))
    print(np.std(number))
    
if count == 0:
    print("let's see some values")
    print(np.mean(number))
    print(np.median(number))
    print(np.std(number))
```

So far this is what I got but I keep getting an error when trying to run it. It's not allowing me to input many values

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You need to put all the inputs into an array, then calculate the statistics of the array at the end.

Comment: `number` is just one number, not all the numbers the user has entered. You can't meaningfully calculate statistics of it.

Comment: Another problem: you never increment `count`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar how do I add inputs into the array? And how should then number be many? When running the code, I put many values and that is when I get the error. I've watched many videos and looked for other examples but haven't been able to do so

Comment: hi @GalaxyCat105 when running it, I can't add more than 1 number

Comment: Append the inputs to a list, then use `np.array(list)` to turn the list into a numpy array.

Comment: Use the term "unexpected result" or "bug" for that. "Error" is almost always used for programming language-thrown errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code Fixed:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = []
number = input("Enter values: ")
number = number.split()
for n in number:
    if n == "0":
        break
    numbers.append(int(n))
print(numbers)
print("Mean is {:.2f}".format(np.mean(numbers)))
print("Median is {:.2f}".format(np.median(numbers)))
print("Standard deviation is {:.2f}".format(np.std(numbers)))
```

You need to enter values separated with space then split at white spaces and store splitted values in an array then convert each element into an int to operate on.

Comment: look at code update to see how to print the result in a neat format with 2 decimal points only